# what is the wp_5_posts table in the database?

Tags: database

I'm wondering what all the `wp_2_*`, `wp_3_*`, `wp_4_*`, and `wp_5_*` tables are in the database. Does anyone know what they are? Some of them in my example are from plugins, but what does the `wp_#` prefix mean? and why are there then duplicates for some of the core database tables?

```
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------------------+
| Tables_in_example           |
+-----------------------------+
| wp_2_commentmeta            |
| wp_2_comments               |
| wp_2_links                  |
| wp_2_options                |
| wp_2_postmeta               |
| wp_2_posts                  |
| wp_2_term_relationships     |
| wp_2_term_taxonomy          |
| wp_2_terms                  |
| wp_3_commentmeta            |
| wp_3_comments               |
| wp_3_links                  |
| wp_3_options                |
| wp_3_postmeta               |
| wp_3_posts                  |
| wp_3_term_relationships     |
| wp_3_term_taxonomy          |
| wp_3_terms                  |
| wp_4_commentmeta            |
| wp_4_comments               |
| wp_4_contact_form_7         |
| wp_4_events                 |
| wp_4_events_categories      |
| wp_4_gwolle_gb_entries      |
| wp_4_gwolle_gb_log          |
| wp_4_links                  |
| wp_4_options                |
| wp_4_postmeta               |
| wp_4_posts                  |
| wp_4_quotescollection       |
| wp_4_term_relationships     |
| wp_4_term_taxonomy          |
| wp_4_terms                  |
| wp_5_commentmeta            |
| wp_5_comments               |
| wp_5_links                  |
| wp_5_options                |
| wp_5_postmeta               |
| wp_5_posts                  |
| wp_5_term_relationships     |
| wp_5_term_taxonomy          |
| wp_5_terms                  |
| wp_blog_versions            |
| wp_blogs                    |
| wp_commentmeta              |
| wp_comments                 |
| wp_domain_mapping           |
| wp_domain_mapping_logins    |
| wp_links                    |
| wp_options                  |
| wp_postmeta                 |
| wp_posts                    |
| wp_redirection_groups       |
| wp_redirection_items        |
| wp_redirection_logs         |
| wp_redirection_modules      |
| wp_registration_log         |
| wp_signups                  |
| wp_site                     |
| wp_sitemeta                 |
| wp_term_relationships       |
| wp_term_taxonomy            |
| wp_terms                    |
| wp_usermeta                 |
| wp_users                    |
| wp_woo_custom_nav_menus     |
| wp_woo_custom_nav_records   |
+-----------------------------+
67 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are from a multisite install.  The numbers represent the blog_id and the tables are created when you add a new site to your network.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Multisite_Table_Details

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#Step_4:_Installing_a_Network